# Retrieve Account's email address in a Gmail app

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I'm writing a Gmail add-on and I need the email address of the user's account.
How can I retrieve it using appsscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Session`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) class:

```
Session.getActiveUser()
```

Note that there are some restrictions when the email address will be available, but for your use case - an add-on which likely receives express permission - this should not be an issue.